# Print Name for Ids stored in other table

Tags: sql, join, database-design

I have two tables first store ID to Name of Company
Companies(ID varchar2(4),CompanyName varchar2(20))

```
1001 - Company1
1002 - Company2
1003 - Company3
1004 - Company4
```

Another table SellerBuyer which stores which company is selling to which company
and each seller or buyer can be null
e.g.

```
(1001,null) 1001 has no buyer
(1002,1003) 1002 is selling to 1003
(1002,1004) 1002 is selling to 1004
(1003,1004) 1003 is selling to 1004
(null,1004) 1004 is also buying from unknown seller.
```

Please help me with SQL which would print name of companies as per data stored in table Companies,SellerBuyer as below

```
(Company1,null)
(Company2,Company3)
(Company2,Company4)
(Company3,Company4)
(null,Company4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Your tables are:

```
Company (ID, CompanyName) 
SellerBuyer(IDSeler,IDBuyer);
```

The secret is to treat Company table as two separate tables, seller for sellers, buyer for buyers,

I started from SellerBuyer and used `left join` to include the nulls.

Also I added the captions SellerName and BuyerName  to the columns.

So your SQL should be something like:

```
select seller.companyName as SellerName, buyer.CompanyName as BuyerName  
from 
  SellerBuyer 
  left join Company as seller on SellerBuyer.IDSeler=seller.ID
  left join Company as buyer on SellerBuyer.IDBuyer=buyer.ID
```

Comment: Thanks SHR for your answer.